# Discord Slack compatible webhook

Tags: laravel, discord, slack

As [per Discord's documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-slackcompatible-webhook) you can use Slack's webhook format.

In a Laravel app I currently have:

```php
$blocks = [
  [
    'type' => 'section',
    'text' => [
      'type' => 'plain_text',
      'text' => 'test',
    ]
  ]
];

$response = Http::post('https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/.../.../slack', [
  'text' => 'Title',
  'blocks' => json_encode($blocks),
]);
```

But only `'Title'` ends up in the message, not the `$blocks` content. The Discord documentation doesn't state that this is not supported, and they refer to [the Slack webhook docs](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks) where it's clearly stated how you build a message using blocks. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Http` will automatically convert objects / arrays to valid `JSON`. So removing `json_encode()` should help your problem.

```
$response = Http::post('https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/.../.../slack', [
  'text' => 'Title',
  'blocks' => $blocks,
]);
```

Comment: Same result, only the `text` value is included in the message. For the Slack webhook to work I actually had to use `json_encode` on `$blocks` that's why I had it there. No clue why these blocks are not being sent.

Comment: But that is not correlating with what is in the documentation where you clearly don't have to encode it, your solution will double encode it

Comment: Yeah I don't quite remember why. But without it as you suggested the blocks aren't sent was well so something else must be wrong.